# Serialize object from within

Tags: php

I have the class `testClass` which has the method `save`. This method saves object to a database. But it needs to serialize object before saving. How can I serialize object from within the class to do that?

```
class testClass {
    private $prop = 777;
    public function save() {
        $serializedObject = serialize(self);
        DB::insert('objects', array('id', 'object'))
                ->values(array(1, $serializedObject))
                ->execute();
    }
}
```

serialize(self) obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to pass `$this` to `serialize()` rather than `self`:

```
$serializedObject = serialize($this);
```

Secondly, unless you are not implementing the [`Serializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface (as from PHP 5.1 ) you need to implement the "magic method" `__sleep()` in order to serialize private or protected properties:

```
public function __sleep() {
    return array('prop');
}
```

This [manual page about serializing objects](http://php.net/manual/de/oop4.magic-functions.php) should help further.

Comment: What if my object `testClass` included objects of other classes as properties, should those other classes implement `__sleep` function as well for private properties?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, they have to. If not, you need to use `__sleep()` and `__wakeup` of `testClass` to get necessary data to serialize and unserialize them again.

Comment: Thanks! <br>If `__sleep()` function is not used, I will loose private properties? <br>Does absence of `__sleep()` affect private methods? <br>Can I make `__sleep` a private function instead of public?

Comment: @Maximus No, `__sleep` and `__wakeup` have to be public

Comment: @Maximus Also check the [`Serializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface. (I forgot to mention this)

Comment: do I need to implement `__sleep` function for both parent and child classes?

Comment: `__sleep()` / `__wakeup()` do not behave different than other methods. You may define the base behaviour in the parent class and refine it in sub classes